# Developing a plugin, ran it through P3 Profiler, shows up slow, but I don't know why

Tags: plugin-development, performance, api, json

I am having an issue with my plugin I'm developing. After using the GoDaddy P3 Plugin profiler, it shows that is taking up a large amount of runtime, but the plugin itself is very minimal.

It just provides a few shortcodes and sanitizes the data entered into them. It basically takes a url, pulls an ID from it, uses an API to get an array of values in JSON format, then takes several of those values from the array and displays them in a div.

I'm not making any queries against the WP database, so I know that's not the issue. It may be the amount of time the API is taking (High School Cube) to return the call, but I'm not sure. I've made sure to follow all of the plugin documentation to the dot and have a very clean, organized file structure with a strict style guide.

Can anyone explain to me why this may be showing up as slow?

Comment: It's almost certainly the api call.

Comment: Okay - so I shouldn't be too concerned with the fact that is isn't loading quickly? And thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: You definitely should.  You could look at using the [transients api](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to cache the results or the high school cube api itself may have some built in features you can use, maybe pagination, result set limiters or maybe you could make your api more specific?  I'm not familiar with their api but many mature ones do have ways to trim down the request.

Comment: The API is very new - its a v1 and barely gets any attention. It does have pagination, but I'm only getting one "event", through a unique ID that pulls the minimum amount of data. I noticed that filtering the amount of data I pulled slowed it down more, so I took off the filter.